# Border and background show up as different colors even when color values are same in CSS

Tags: html, css, border, background-color

Is it possible to make the color of the border the same as the background color? In my example, it should have the same color but the border color is always a bit darker than the background color.

```css
.box {
    min-width: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">foo</div>
```

Comment: It is the same color, it's just overlapping.

Comment: Or use a padding instead of a border.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should specify  `background-clip: padding-box;` (or `content-box`) because, by default, this property is set to `border-box` thus the background also covers the area under the borders.

The effect you're obtaining is actually due to an overlapped transparency (with a full-solid colour you wouldn't notice the issue), so that's the reason you're seeing the border a bit darker than the background colour

```css
.box {
    --bgcolor: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    min-width: 50px;
    background: var(--bgcolor);
    background-clip:  padding-box;
    border: 10px solid var(--bgcolor);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">foo</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to fcalderan's answer, you could also make the `border-color` transparent so the div's background color simply comes through:

```css
.box {
    min-width: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">foo</div>
```

Comment: Isn't the `10px` redundant when its transparent?

Comment: No, if you inspect the element you'll see the border is still physically there, it's just literally trasnparent :-)

Comment: Yeah, thats what I meant. But your right, physically the border is still there. :)

Comment: Yep, just another way of achieving a similar result - there's always more than one way to skin a cat!

Answer (score 5):

Or it can be another decision - just emulate your border by box-shadow

```
.box {
    min-width: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow:0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need not write any extra line

```css
.box {
    min-width: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border:10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">foo</div>
```